# Api Call when user is closing the broswer

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have created a video calling feature on my website (angular+spring) using jitsi-meet. I three call statuses maintained in the database for tracking i.e not_initiated, initiated, call_end. The workflow is as follows:

1. user A joins the call. At this time call status is not_initiated.
2. user B joins the call and now the call status changes to initiated and a timer is started.
3. Whenever any user hangups the call, a callback API is fired to the backend server which changes the status of the call to call_end and deducts the amount from the user wallet according to the time

The problem that I am facing is that I need to show a timer to both users and it needs to be in sync with both the user browsers.
The second issue is that if a user closes the browser then the server never receives a callback request in which case I am never able to change the status of the call to call_end. How do I ensure that a callback is received from the browser?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

currently, the timer is already in sync with other users in the same room in jitsi meet? here you just have to start/control the timer from the backend independent of browsers only in the "initiated" state.

secondly, when you close a browser tab your connection is gone but that doesn't mean you have ended it. if you wanna put a logic like "call_end" for every connection loss immediately then it would hamper conference performance as the network is not stable for all users and it needs to retry for reconnecting. You may set a timeout of few seconds after which you will forcefully end the call from the backend if 1 user lost connection is 2 person call.

and moreover, to get more attention and answers from friendly more experienced users, please post in [jitsi community](https://community.jitsi.org/). Thanks..!